# Method to load browser history after closing and re-opening the browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview

I am trying to build a mobile browser(Android & IOS) using `Webview`, however this question applies to normal desktop browser.

All browsers out in the market(whether mobile or desktop) remember browsing history for each tab even after closing the app and re-opening them. How do I achieve this behaviour?

I have looked into `window.history.pushState` and replaceState, but I am not sure if this is the right usage for my case. What I need to do is save the browsing history before app is closed, and when app opens, I need to load that saved history to the `Webview` so that users can still navigate back from where they closed.

What I have thought of is pushing all the urls visited in an array for each tab and save it before app closes. Then upon opening the app, using this array I can inject the urls in Webview somehow. I have tried methods such as

```
history.pushState({}, '', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com') // assuming stackoverflow is the previous website of the closed tab.
```

but this doesn't work, since you can only change the path, not the domain itself.

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you are using browser you can use Session Storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @ZivBen-Or thanks for the answer. Though how would I use sessionStorage to inject the history to the browser? Besides, they expire when browser closes

Comment: You are right, you should use `localStorage` insted (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
To push the history, you can use the `history.replaceState` on page load.

Comment: History API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @ZivBen-Or Yep, already checked replaceState method, but it doesn't allow to replace a fresh, different new url, i.e. "https://www.stackoverflow.com". I could only replace with same origin domain , like '/bar'